# How to give URL in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to create a hyperlink in shell script.

I have one azure link. So if the script runs the output will be the link. That link should be clickable, and it should be redirected.

Comment: `if link is clicked` ... what link are you talking about?

Comment: I have one azure link...So if the script runs the output will be the link..that link should be clickable....and it should be redirected

Comment: Text in the terminal is just text. The terminal is not a web browser. Some terminals are able to detect URLs and you may click links by pressing some extra key (e.g. in `gnome-terminal` and in iTerm on macOS). This is a feature of the _terminal_, not of the shell or of the script.  Please clarify your question by editing it, adding information about what terminal your are running.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, You can use `echo -e`, on gnome-terminal, eg.,

```
 echo -e '\e]8;;http://example.com\aThis is a hyperlink\e]8;;\a'
```

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while clicking on the string.

Comment: am getting the output as this is a hyperlink...where should i click on terminal

Comment: click on "This is a hyperlink" string **by holding Ctrl**

Comment: am using bash terminal...this is not working..

Comment: No, your *shell* is bash. What program do you use for your teminal? What is your OS?

Comment: AM using amazon linux ec2 machine...I have one url i should make it clickable....so when i click from my terminal it should be redirected to respective goggle page

Comment: @samikshap You say that you want to click it in the terminal.  What terminal are you using?

Answer (score 3):

```
printf '\e]8;;http://example.com\e\\This is a link\e]8;;\e\\\n'
```

Hold Ctrl while clicking on the text.

or simplest :

```
xdg-open http://www.example.com/
```

See also: https://gist.github.com/egmontkob/eb114294efbcd5adb1944c9f3cb5feda

Comment: `echo -e` did not work from within my `while` loop,`printf` did the trick, thanks